# GtrendsR granular data download

Tags: r, download, google-trends, gtrendsr

I downloaded Google Trends data on a daily basis using the following code

```
 trend = gtrends(c("google","apple"),  geo= ("US-CA-803"), time = ("2017-09-01 
 2017-10-30")
 write.csv(trend$interest_over_time, file= " 
 C:\\Users\\Downloads\\LAdaily.csv")
```

*I there a way where I can download data on a granular level? (minute by minute from 7pm-11pm for instance*
Replies are really appreciated.